# package clashes with class of same name gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

> Error:(4, 1) error: package  clashes with class of same name
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.

who can explain, what does it mean. i didn't find answer on the internet

Comment: up date your app build gradle file make sure your jdk version is up to 7

Comment: Do you have any class defined in your project, which also is the name of an existing package?

Comment: i'm using java-8-openjdk

Comment: Jolta, i thought that it was problem with ApplicationTest class. but you was right, i forgot that i created class named "test". thanx

Comment: Simply put, check for a class with the same name of a package. This usually happens when using an IDE, like IntelliJ, the user tries to create a package and select "Create Class" by accident.